# files are sending properly but not receiving properly

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

here i am trying to transfer multiple file via socket programming when i sent it, its  sending correctly but in receiving function first file receive properly (file and its content inside it) but 2nd file be like file+content so my function is unable to find file name and its break help me to find my mistake...

server code -

```
forbidden_extensions = [".exe", ".dll"]

def receive_files():  #images properly but single
    try:
        while True:
            filename = file_client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            print('filename---', filename)

            directory = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Received3')
            os.makedirs(directory, exist_ok=True)
            
            destination = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            print(f'destination : {destination}')  
            with open(destination, 'wb') as file:
                data = file_client_socket.recv(1024)
                print(f'data to be receive : {data}')
                file.write(data)
                time.sleep(2)
                
                while len(data) == 1024:
                    data = file_client_socket.recv(1024)
                    # print(f'data to be sent inside while : {data}')
                    file.write(data)
                    # time.sleep(2)  # Add time delay of 10 seconds between receiving chunks
                
                     

            print('File successfully received:', filename)

            connection_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            log_message = f"{filename} File successfully received from {socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())} at {connection_time}\n"

            with open("connection_log.txt", "a") as file:
                file.write(log_message)

            messagebox.showinfo("File Received ", f"File '{filename}' received successfully!")

            # time.sleep(2)  # Add time delay of 2 seconds after receiving a file

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred in receive_files(): {str(e)}")
    # except (NotADirectoryError,FileNotFoundError):
    #    if not filename:
    #             print('inside not filename')
                # If no filename is received, it means all files have been received
                # break
                # file2=filename[0]
                # destination1 = os.path.join(destination1,file2)
                # print(f'file if not filename : {file2} ---------- {destination1}')
```

client code-

```
def send_files():
    try:
        selected_indices = listbox.curselection()
        if selected_indices:
            files = [listbox.get(index) for index in selected_indices]

            for file_path in files:
                filename = os.path.basename(file_path)
                print(f'file path : {file_path}')

                # Send the filename
                file_server_socket.send(filename.encode('utf-8'))

                # Send the file
                with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
                    data = file.read()
                    # print(f'data to be sent : {data}')
                    file_server_socket.send(data)
                    print(f"File sent: {filename}")
                    
                    time.sleep(2)   
                
                print("All files sent.")
                connection_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

                # Write the log message for each file to a file
                with open("client_connection_log.txt", "a") as file:
                    # for filename in files:
                        log_message = f"{filename} File successfully sent at {connection_time}\n"
                        file.write(log_message)

        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("No File Selected", "Please select at least one file to send.")
    except NameError:
        pass
```

Comment: what do you mean by **2nd file be like file+content** here?

Comment: You always use recv(1024). This is very naive (what if there's more than 1k bytes transmitted). Even if fewer than 1k bytes are sent there's no guarantee that they'll be received with one call to recv(). I suggest you take a look at sendmsg() and recvmsg() in conjunction with pack() and unpack() from the struct module

Comment: @Kulasangar i mean if A want to send 2 file to B then B receive 1st file correctly but second file he didn't receive when we look into CMD we can see it receives file name like this - <filename><content> then function realise that no file to share so it break

Comment: @poojatesting recv(N) will receive **at most** N bytes. If you remember that fact, you should be able to fix your code

Answer (score 0):

DarkKnight rightly pointed out that *recv(N) will receive at most N bytes.* You remarkably rely on this fact when receiving the filename, but disregard it when receiving the file data. Errors:

1. There is no indication of where in the receive stream the filename ends and the file data begin.
2. There is no indication of where in the receive stream the file data of one file end and the next filename begins.

Possible fixes:

1. Separate name and data by a newline and read the name accordingly.
2. Transmit the file size and receive accordingly.

E. g. in the client:

```
                # Send the filename
                file_server_socket.sendall((filename+'\n').encode())
                # Send the file
                data = open(file_path, "rb").read()
                file_server_socket.sendall((str(len(data))+'\n').encode())
                file_server_socket.sendall(data)
```

in the server:

```
            f = file_client_socket.makefile('b')
            # read newline-terminated filename; return if connection closed
            filename = f.readline().rstrip().decode()
            if not filename: return
            filesize = int(f.readline())
…
            with open(destination, 'wb') as file:
                while filesize: # size remaining to receive
                    data = f.read(filesize)
                    file.write(data)
                    filesize -= len(data)
```

Comment: its not taking filesize i put some print to troubleshoot program is not working when it reach to filesize

Comment: Where did you _put some print_? What does it print? What does _is not working_ mean?

Answer (score 0):

A common convention when transmitting data over sockets is to provide a length value as a preamble to the actual data. In that way the server side can read a well-known number of bytes and interpret that as meaning the amount of data to follow.

Here are a couple of functions that demonstrate how this can be done:

```
from struct import pack, unpack
from socket import socket

FMT = '=Q'
FMTL = 8

def send(s: socket, data: str|bytes) -> None:
    # ensure bytes
    if isinstance(data, str):
        data = data.encode()
    # portable length
    mlen = pack(FMT, len(data))
    # send the length preamble along with the actual data
    s.sendmsg([mlen, data])


def recv(s: socket) -> bytes:
    # the length of the header is well-known
    header, *_ = s.recvmsg(FMTL)
    # convert it
    length, *_ = unpack(FMT, header)
    # return the data
    return s.recvmsg(length)[0]
```